# Update an Oracle table using listagg statement on the same table

Tags: oracle, listagg

I have a table that contains one or more records for each item. Each item can contain multiple sub-items (boards) and so the Itemid is often replicated with each record showing the division category (a number) that the Item/sub-item combo resides in:

```
ItemId      Board#  Division

142585109   0   6   
142585114   0   3   
142585116   0   1   
142585120   0   4   
142585197   0   5   
142585197   2   4   
142585197   3   3   
142585197   5   6   
142585197   8   1   
142585294   0   4   
142585317   0   1
```

I want to update the table and aggregate all of the division values (as a comma separated string) in a new field in this table, something like:

```
ItemId      Board#  AggDivisions
142585109   0   6   
142585114   0   3   
142585116   0   1   
142585120   0   4   
142585197   0   1,3,4,5,6   
142585294   0   4   
142585317   0   1
```

I used a ListAgg query to do the aggregation which works correctly but when I tried to incorporate this into an update query, I end up with multiple duplicates in the aggregated field for each record.
Here is my update attempt:

```
update itemtable dd
    set aggregateddivisions = (SELECT Listagg(division, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY division)
                   FROM itemtable ev
                   WHERE ev.itemid = dd.itemid
                  )
    where exists (select 1 
                  from itemtable ev
                  where ev.itemid = dd.itemid
                 );
```

How can I update the table with the aggregated list of values from the same table without ending up with duplicates?

Comment: You'll have to **delete** rows you don't want. They won't *automagically* disappear just because you updated the table.

Comment: Storing comma-separated values in a string field is usually a bad idea - it makes it much harder to work with the individual values. It would usually be better to keep the separate rows and aggregate when needed; or in a (maybe materialzed) view. Why do you want to make this change?

Comment: Ever heard of "first normal form"? You can use Google to search for the phrase. Your data is currently in first normal form. What you show as the result of your process is no longer in first normal form. You are going in the wrong direction. WHY do you think you need to store data in the new way, rather than the existing one? This will cause endless headaches in the future.